# If input image is empty give me error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with some inputs with that form I want to make some edit in database. I want if exist a picture in databse to keep it not to replace with blank space. If input is empty I get the error from if condition branch else `echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";`. If I upload an image everything works fine. Here is my code

```
<?php

include "../../../config/config.php";
session_start();

if (isset($_GET['car'])) {
    $car = $_GET['car'];
} else {
    die("Not found");
}


if (isset($_POST['submit-edit'])) {



    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['title-edit']);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description-edit']);
    $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['category-edit']);



    /* ----------------------- MAIN IMAGE  -------------------------- */
    $target_dir = "../../../img/found/thumbs-category/";
    $target_file2 = "" . basename($_FILES["img-edit"]["name"]);
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img-edit"]["name"]);

    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["img-edit"]["size"] > 100000) {
        $_SESSION['image-size'] = 1;

        header("Location: /dashboard/views/edit.php?car=$car");
        exit();
    }
//    
    //Allow certain file formats
    if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != NULL) {
        $_SESSION['image-format'] = 1;

        header("Location: /dashboard/views/edit.php?car=$car");
        exit();
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {

    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img-edit"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {


        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            exit();
        }


        $query = "UPDATE cars
            SET title='" . $title . "', text='" . $description . "', image='" . $target_file2 . "', fk_cars_first='" . $category . "' WHERE car=" . $car;


        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
//                var_dump($query);
//                exit();
        if ($result) {


            header("Location: /dashboard/views/edit.php?car=$car");
        } else {
//          
            echo "error";
            exit();
            header("Location: /dashboard/views/edit.php?car=$car");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

More exactly in my database I have

```
title | description | image  |  fk_category
test    more text     car.jpg   tuning
```

When I want to edit the the database I use the form and if the input with type="file" is empty I want to keep the actual path not to erase.. Right the code do something like this..I set the submit button and the database look like

```
title      | description | image  |  fk_category
testedited |   ed!t      |        |  tuning_tex_edited
```

If is empty get the error `Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.` and in database the path is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this code:

```
if ($_FILES['img-edit']){
  foreach($_FILES['img-edit']['name'] as $a=>$v){

    //Check if empty
    if(!empty($_FILES['img-edit']['name'][$a])){

       //Check size of image
       if($_FILES['img-edit']['size'][$a]>0){

         //Now code here

       }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img-edit"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) { //if you have a valid file it will replace the image name
$query = "UPDATE cars
        SET title='" . $title . "', text='" . $description . "', image='" . $target_file2 . "', fk_cars_first='" . $category . "' WHERE car=" . $car; 

    } else { //if you dont have any image it will leave with the older one
$query = "UPDATE cars
        SET title='" . $title . "', text='" . $description . "', fk_cars_first='" . $category . "' WHERE car=" . $car;
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        exit();
    }
```